# Hiding fields in Flask-Admin depending on logged in user?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin, flask-security

I have `Users` and `Roles` in my Flask app thanks to Flask-Security.

For some roles I would like to hide certain fields in the forms created by Flask-Admin.

I know about customizing ModelViews with eg. `form_create_rules = ('title', 'file')` but while instantiating a ModelView there isn't access to the current request so `current_user.has_role(USER_ROLE)` can't be called.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you cannot access the request while instantiating a ModelView? Anyway, here is an example https://github.com/sasaporta/flask-security-admin-example/blob/master/main.py

Comment: Yes, `current_user` is not available then. It's only available in `is_accessible()` and `_handle_view()` (like they do in the example). But setting `self.form_create_rules` in those methods has no effect :( .

Comment: You can change `self.form_create_rules` and regenerate forms, but it is discouraged - forms are cached for performance reasons.

Instead, you can override `create_form` and `edit_form` and return different forms (or remove fields from existing form).

See here: https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/base.py#L1242

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way of achieving this is to create multiple view classes and register these view classes against their appropriate roles. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33653754/2800058) on how to register roles to views. Using view inheritance you can keep common functionality in the "base" class.

For example, suppose we have a user table that implements the Flask-Security mixin and we want the role "admin" to be able to read/set the active field and anyone with the role "user" not to see this field. The class `AdminView` is defined  in the referenced answer.

```
class AdminUserView(AdminView):

    column_list = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'roles', 'active']

    form_columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'active', 'roles']

    # Other common functionality here

class UserView(AdminUserView): 

    # Just redefine the columns that can be seen/edited

    column_list = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'roles']

    form_columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'roles']

# register your views and remember to set a unique endpoint as we are using the same model in multiple views

admin.add_view(AdminUserView(model=User, session=db.session, category="Accounts", name="Users", endpoint="users_admin", roles_accepted=["admin"]))
admin.add_view(UserView(model=User, session=db.session, category="Accounts", name="Users", endpoint="users_user", roles_accepted=["user"]))
```

Comment: can not add roles_accepted TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'roles_accepted'