# Flask admin roles adding roles_accepted to add_view

Tags: flask-admin, flask-mongoengine

I have managed to get roles working with this code but!

```py
class Roled(object):
    def is_accessible(self):
        roles_accepted = getattr(self, 'roles_accepted', None)
        if flask_login.current_user.is_authenticated:
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=flask_login.current_user.id)
            for role in user.roles:
                for permission in role.permissions:
                    if permission == "admin":
                        return flask_login.current_user.is_authenticated

    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        # redirect to login page if user doesn't have access
        return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))


class AdminView(Roled, ModelView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.roles_accepted = kwargs.pop('roles_accepted', list())
        super(AdminView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class TranslationView(Roled, ModelView):
    column_filters = ['eng']
    column_searchable_list = ('eng','geo', 'name')
```

Now I have a problem adding roles_accapted to each add_view when adding flask admin views as it was in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532988/hiding-fields-in-flask-admin-depending-on-logged-in-user/37554001#comment91878722_37554001)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TranslationView` should inherit from the `AdminView` class. i.e.

```py
class TranslationView(AdminView):
    column_filters = ['eng']
    column_searchable_list = ('eng','geo', 'name')
```

Comment: Ok. I understand that but how to pass roles_accepted to AdminView ?
this does not work

`admin.add_view(AdminUserView(model=User, session=db.session, category="Accounts", name="Users", endpoint="users_admin", roles_accepted=["admin"]))`

May it is because I was not inheriting TranslationView from AdminView ?

Comment: @BeqaBukhradze - taken to chat.

Comment: sorry did not get it ?

Comment: @BeqaBukhradze - go to [https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180667/flask-admin-roles-accepted](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180667/flask-admin-roles-accepted)